# Unit test code for a private median-of-three function, using reflection

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, junit

A Junit test class is used to test the class LibraryCounter. Reflection was used to test the private methods. This made the code much more complicated.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class LibraryCounterTest {

 public LibraryCounterTest() { }

 @Test
 public void medianEasyTest() {
     System.out.println("median");
     int[] sample = {7,8,9};
     Class[] args = new Class[3];
     args[0] = int[].class;
     args[1] = Integer.TYPE;
     args[2] = Integer.TYPE;

     try {
           Method m = LibraryCounter.class.getDeclaredMethod("median", args);
          m.setAccessible(true);
          try {
              Object o = m.invoke(null, sample, 0, sample.length-1);
              int result = (int)o;
              assertEquals(8, result);
          } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(LibraryCounterTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(LibraryCounterTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

     assertEquals(7, sample[0]);
     assertEquals(8, sample[1]);
     assertEquals(9, sample[2]);
 }
}
```

This is just the first and simplest test.  The method being tested has the following signature `private static int median(int[], int, int)` If the method was `public` then everything inside the outermost `try` could be condensed to one line.

Here is the method being tested from the LibraryCounter class:

```
/*
*Sorts first, center and last element, swaps the new center element with the one before the new last and returns its value.
*/
private static int median(int[] sample, int start, int end) {
    if(sample.length < 3) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("arrays of length three or greater");
    }

    int center = start + ((end-start)/2);

    if(sample[start] > sample[end])
       swap(sample, start, end);

    if(sample[start] > sample[center])
       swap(sample, start, center);

    if(sample[center] > sample[end])
       swap(sample, center, end);

int secondLast = end - 1

    swap(sample, center, secondLast );

    return sample[secondLast];

}

//swaps two elements in array given their positions
private static void swap(int[] sample, int x, int y) {
    int temp = sample[x];
    sample[x] = sample[y];
    sample[y] = temp;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's really unclear what your asking.  Are you looking for a cleaner way to test private methods? My initial  reaction is that you shouldn't be testing the private method, but without the class under test it's hard to give concrete advice.

Comment: Yes. How to make the code cleaner. I have red it's bad to test private methods but am curious why? Testing is good so why all of a sudden is it bad if the method is private?

Comment: Private methods are implementation details of the classes you are testing.  By writing tests against the privates, you tightly couple your tests to the implementation which makes refactoring difficult.  Generally if a section of private functionality is big enough that you would want to test it then there is a good chance that it could be refactored (possibly by class extraction) to make it more testable.  However, as I said, without the actual class under test it is all speculation.

Comment: You are likely to get a better response if you post the entire test class and the class(es) it is testing.

Comment: This is for choosing a quicksort pivot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said in my comments, I'm not a huge fan of testing private methods.  It couples the tests very closely to the implementation of your class which makes even simple refactorings much harder than they need to be.  That said, lets have a look at your test.

**Naming**

`medianEasyTest` tells me nothing really about what the test is expecting.  `median` is the name of the method you're calling.  `EasyTest` tells me nothing about what you're passing, or what you're expecting back.  This doesn't make the intention of the test easy to read.

**Exceptions**

You're catching exceptions in your test and more than that, whilst you're logging them, you're swallowing the exceptions.  I *really* don't like that.  If your code throws an exception, you should let the exception escape the test and fail it.  Having the test fail on `assertEquals(7, sample[0]);` when it's actually failed because it threw an `IllegalAccessException` is just confusing.

**Setup**

If you're going to be running multiple tests against the same private methods, then it makes sense to do a lot of the prep work either in a method called explicitly, or in a `Before` method on the test class (notice that I'm not catching any exceptions.  If they happen, because your class structure changes you want it to fail:

```
@Before
public void setupPrivateCalls() {
   Class[] args = new Class[3];
   args[0] = int[].class;
   args[1] = Integer.TYPE;
   args[2] = Integer.TYPE;

   medianMethod = LibraryCounter.class.getDeclaredMethod("median", args);
   medianMethod.setAccessible(true);
}

Method medianMethod;
```

**Double checking**

You're checking that sample hasn't been updated at the end of your test.  Do you really need to do that?

**Putting it together**

Putting all of that together, you end up with an actual test method that looks more like this:

```
public void testMedianIs8From789() {
     System.out.println("median");
     int[] sample = {7,8,9};

     int result  = (int)medianMethod.invoke(null, sample, 0, sample.length-1);
     assertEquals(8, result);
 }
```

**Exceptions from privates**

This is probably subjective, but I don't like the way your private method is throwing an exception:

private static int median(int[] sample, int start, int end) {
    if(sample.length < 3) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("arrays of length three or greater");
    }

If your private throws that exception, it's because something under your classes control (one of it's public methods) has failed to supply the right data.  Validation should be performed at the public interface to the class, you shouldn't need to perform it again in your privates.

Comment: Re: Exceptions. The exception must be caught or thrown, or the code wont compile. So you're saying it's better to throw it? I've never thrown code in Junit but I guess it's the same. I wanted to confirm I understood you correctly.

Comment: Do you still get compilation errors if you mark the test as throws?  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31423712/592182

Comment: Got it working. For some reason Netbeans suggested `add throw clause for java.lang.SecurityException` but after I threw `java.lang.NoSuchElementException` this suggestion went away. Any idea why it suggested `SecurityException`or was this a mistake?

Comment: @Dlittle I would assume it's because `getDeclaredMethod` can throw `SecurityException`, however I don't use Netbeans so I don't know how strict it is.